# Расположить в порядке возрастания

Tags: pascal

Введите последовательность целых чисел и напечатайте их в порядке возрастания. Повторяющиеся действия оформить в виде процедуры.

Comment: @voksa, укажите, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Я не знаю с чего начать(я вообще не понимаю этот язык программирование, ) объясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заводите массив, вводите количество элементов последовательности,через read или readln вводите числа, потом заносите их в массив и сортируйте в порядке возрастания. Про методы сортировки массивов, можно почитать [тут](http://www.vzmakh.ru/info/pascal/modules/page14.html). Вообще, конечно желательно показывать какие-нибудь наработки. Так вероятность в том, что вам помогут, увеличивается.

Comment: Извините , не могли бы дать ссылку где можно выполнить эту работу ? или скачать программу.